# Powerapps: problem specifying record id for patch function

Tags: sharepoint-online

Having trouble getting a seemingly simple patch command to work. I have a SharePoint list (myList) and want to update the title for the specified record when clicking a button (OnSelect).

PowerApps is giving me errors for ID_Datacard; invalid name. Tried a global variable, type does not match. The only thing that does work is manually entering a number like 1. I can get the ID for the record and display it in a label without problems, I just can't get patch to accept it.

Patch('myList', {ID: ID_Datacard.Default}, {Title: myTitle})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect ID_Datacard.Default is not a number, hence a type mismatch error. Try converting ID_Datacard.Default to number using `Value` function:

```
Patch('myList', {ID: Value(ID_Datacard.Default)}, {Title: myTitle})
```

I've just tried 3 different methods of Patching and all of them worked just fine:

```
Patch(ListA, currentItem, {Title:'myTitle'})
```

or

```
Patch(ListA, {ID: currentItem.ID}, {Title:"New Title!"})
```

or

```
Patch(ListA, {ID: Value("2")}, {Title:"New Title!"})
```

You can also output ID_Datacard.Default to some label for debugging purposes to see if it actually contains a valid ID.

Comment: Those are good examples. Strange thing is it was working fine yesterday.  It appears now my whole form is just flaking out, acting very weird in IE and Chrome, yet works fine in PowerApps preview. Any chance these files can get corrupted?

Comment: Way more flashes than normal postback, and now my combo box is flying off to the opposite side of the form, this is crazy. I think its posessed.

Comment: I had to go back quite a number of versions to flush out the weird behavior I was picking up with this form. Once I found a stable version your suggestions were very helpful in properly identifying the ID and patching without error. Thank you.

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov This is probably the most useful: `Patch(ListA, {ID: Value(lblID.Text)}, frmStuff.Updates, frmOtherStuff.Updates)` - I was able to derive that from these examples - THANKS! For my project, I added the ID field on the first form, renamed the control to `lblID`, and then made the datacard's `visible` property `false`. Then I could patch all of the forms together (there were more). Called `ResetForm()` on the forms I needed to clear, `RequestHide()` at the end. Boom! Finally able to update an existing item instead of just creating new ones!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to patch the record by using a parameter as the ID in the patch, then reference it like this:

```
Patch(ListA, {ID: Value(Param("MyParamaterName"))}, Title:"New Title!"})
```